# A similarity measure with binary data: does this one have a name?

Tags: distance-functions, similarities, jaccard-similarity

There are many binary similarity measures (e.g. Jaccard, Sorensen, etc), each of them is sensitive to different properties of the compared sets. I would like to use the metric $S=\frac{N_{A\bigcap B}}{min(N_{A}; N_{B})}$, where $N_{A}$ is the count of set $A$. So basically I divide the size of the intersection by the size of the smaller set. I am sure I am not the first who found this out, and maybe it has some pretty name. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your measure seems to resolve to a distance defined by Simpson. See [A Survey of Binary Similarity and Distance Measures](http://www.iiisci.org/Journal/CV$/sci/pdfs/GS315JG.pdf) page 44, equation 45.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Also this brief compendium is very nice, thanks for that too.