# I have 20 symptoms and need to do a hierarchical cluster analysis? Which method is appropriate?

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

and thank you in advance for any suggestions. I have 20 binary symptoms (for example, anxiety yes/no, depression yes/no), and i have to do a cluster analysis for my research project in order to see which symptoms cluster together. However, i find this quite challenging, as i don't know which method of hierarchical cluster analysis i should use and what distance measure. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

***Any help would be highly appreciated*** Ok, I did a quick search on CrossValidated and found that there are several similar questions with excellent answers. [This one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/116859/9233) shows hierarchical clustering is very well suited to binary data. Two step clustering is also mentioned . There are many similarity measures for binary data. See [A Survey of Binary Similarity and Distance Measures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/155161/9233) for example. Both the answers linked to above contain plenty of additional links for further reading.

*Kudos to the authors for providing much better answers than I could.*

Best thing is to read around the topic and then start playing with various hierarchical clustering models and simialrity measures. There is a simple introduction to R's [hclust algorithm here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/hierarchical-clustering-in-r-2/) and another cross validated [question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86318/clustering-a-binary-matrix) with R code included to get you going. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Martino, i have read quite a bit about it but it becomes more and more complicated. Thank you for your help anyways. All the best.